# Excel Check-Box see if checked

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I have a chekcbox that has transformed into a AutoShape type
as in if you run the follwing code you get Type 1:
Print ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 5").Type
1

Is there a way to see if it is checked?

I have tried the following codes but they do not work:

`ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 5").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1`

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box " & i).ControlFormat.Value = False
```

Comment: A line like that won't do anything on its own as not valid syntax. You need to put a msgbox in front or debug.print or type it in the immediate window with a ? in front.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that checks a numbered CheckBox:

```
Function GetCheckBoxValue(i As Integer) As Boolean
    GetCheckBoxValue = (ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box " & i).OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1)
End Function
```

You can then use that to test the value in an `IF` statement for instance like so:

```
Sub test()
    If GetCheckBoxValue(5) Then
        MsgBox "It's ticked"
    Else
        MsgBox "It's not ticked"
    End If
End Sub
```

Or you can run through them and test them all with:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 1 To 5
        If GetCheckBoxValue(x) Then
            MsgBox "Check Box " & x & " is ticked"
        Else
            MsgBox "Check Box " & x & " is not ticked"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```